# Is it possible to start/stop the mdworker process without disabling Spotlight?

Tags: spotlight, indexing

Spotlight indexing has always been a problem on all of my Macs, and therefore, the first thing I always do on a new machine is disabling it. I use a different launcher, so it is OK. Yet, disabling Spotlight automatically prevents searching emails and notes.

I have always asked myself if it is possible to just create a Spotlight index once, and manually update it via the command line at regular intervals of time (once a week, for example).

Is it possible to just create the Spotlight, without the `mdworker` process constantly hogging my CPU and RAM? I refuse to believe that a smart company like Apple has programmed the indexing infrastructure in such a dumb and coupled way that the worker should always be up and running.

Comment: Your question reads to me like it's an XY problem. You have a problem (X) and decide the solution is Y, so you've come here asking a question about Y rather than the actual problem. My suggestion would be to ask another question about the fact that _spotlight indexing has always been a problem on all of [your] Macs_. Perhaps we can help you sort that out once for all? Typically, while the mdworker process can slow things down, this is usually only the case initially while it's doing the initial index. Granted, sometimes this can take a couple of days if you have a lot of data.

Comment: Also the case when deleting or adding a lot of data...  I just lost 10% battery in 20 minutes on a 2016 MBP to the sudden need to index.  mdworker is out of control a decade later.  It should at least be mindful of the environment, e.g. battery vs AC